# Echo custom post meta from options array

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

The code below comes from:

```
var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID)).
```

How can I echo the value of artist_seo_description from my PHP script?

```
array(5) { ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1425587233:1" } ["photo-artist_tfuse_post_options"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1182) "a:4:{s:25:"photo-artist_slider_image";s:0:"";s:28:"photo-artist_slides_interval";s:4:"6000";s:22:"photo-artist_seo_title";s:21:"Crest Drive Residence";s:28:"photo-artist_seo_description";s:985:"This is the description field.";}" } ["_wp_old_slug"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "crest-drive-renovation" } ["photo-artist_post_viewed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Comment: do you mean `photo-artist_seo_description`? it's saved under the key `photo-artist_tfuse_post_options`.

Comment: Yes. How can I grab that value from the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_post_custom` isn't a great function if you're trying to get values that are serialized, you have to unserialize them yourself.

A better function is `get_post_meta`:

```
$options = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'photo-artist_tfuse_post_options', true );
echo $options['photo-artist_seo_description'];
```